# How do i display digital pulse in android using Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

I would like to build an android app to take the audio data from microphone and to display both the analog signal and digital gear pulse. I had succeeded in developing the app to display analog signal in graph with plotting corresponding samples on it, but so far i am unable to display the digital pulse for the same, can anyone help regarding this.,

Thanks in advance...!

Comment: kind of extremely general question, maybe if you could specify what issues are making you "unable to display the digital pulse"?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Ya sure Zerkz will update this with code and issues shortly.